# How to truncate tail each line of multiline UILabel

Tags: uilabel, line-breaks, multiline, multilinestring

`NSString *longStr = @"AAAAAAAAAA\nBBBBB\nCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC";`

How to make this truncation with UILabel for some label width:

```
AAA...  
BBB...
CCC...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use separate labels for each line and use `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`.

Hint :  Split the text over `\n` and iterate over the array obtained.

EDIT :

Find the number of characters possible per line in the width of the UILabel and then change your text.

Split over `\n` -> Iterate over the Strings -> Get SubString of length equal to the `max width of the UILabel - some value` -> Append trailing dots to that SubString and add the resultant string to `tempString` -> Create UILabel and assign `tempString` to it

This would give you the desired result.

Comment: I cant use each label for each line. It will works bad and laggy to print 1000+ lines text. I need 1 label for this.

Comment: "Find the number of characters possible per line in the width of the UILabel" - I think it is not possible, because each char has own width.

Comment: You can do that by finding number of characters that can fit in specified width.